# Find item in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In the following data structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 28,
    "country": "Brazil",
    "country_code": "BR",
    "country_population": 201103330,
    "province": "",
    "last_updated": "2020-04-03T01:40:00.724616Z",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-14.235",
      "longitude": "-51.9253"
    },
    "latest": {
      "confirmed": 8044,
      "deaths": 324,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    "timelines": {
      "confirmed": {
        "latest": 8044,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "deaths": {
        "latest": 324,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "recovered": {
        "latest": 0,
        "timeline": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How do I get `"timeline"` items, from `"timelines"` key?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide at least a piece of code of what you tried for now..

```py
d = [
  {
    "id": 28,
    "country": "Brazil",
    "country_code": "BR",
    "country_population": 201103330,
    "province": "",
    "last_updated": "2020-04-03T01:40:00.724616Z",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-14.235",
      "longitude": "-51.9253"
    },
    "latest": {
      "confirmed": 8044,
      "deaths": 324,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    "timelines": {
      "confirmed": {
        "latest": 8044,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "deaths": {
        "latest": 324,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "recovered": {
        "latest": 0,
        "timeline": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```py
print(d[0]["timelines"]["confirmed"]["timeline"])
```

By the way :

```
"timeline": {
  "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
}
```

Looks weird for me does `timeline` should be an `array` instead of a `object` ?

Comment: data structure extracted from this wrapper -> [https://pypi.org/project/COVID19Py/]

Answer (score 0):

```
print([[i, data[0]['timelines'][i]['timeline']] for i in data[0]['timelines']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does indeed have an issue

"JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 24 column 9 (char 558)"

Which in turn is your timeline as posted above

"timeline": {
"2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
"2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,    <----
"2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,

JSONs have many formatting issues, and you may have to develop your own method of reading them if they are out of the general norm, I've had to do this a few times.

```
import json

x = """[{
    "id": 28,
    "country": "Brazil",
    "country_code": "BR",
    "country_population": 201103330,
    "province": "",
    "last_updated": "2020-04-03T01:40:00.724616Z",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-14.235",
      "longitude": "-51.9253"
    },
    "latest": {
      "confirmed": 8044,
      "deaths": 324,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    "timelines": {
      "confirmed": {
        "latest": 8044,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "deaths": {
        "latest": 324,
        "timeline": {
          "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
          "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
        }
      },
      "recovered": {
        "latest": 0,
        "timeline": {}
      }
    }
  }]"""

y = json.loads(x)
print(y)
```